# Create Transactional Replication in SQL with variable table name as a source

Tags: sql-server, transactions, replication

I want to create a Data Warehouse Database for reporting.
One of the requests is to check in real time the production status per production line.
The database is designed to have monthly tables as per below (tblName_+yyyymm):

```
tblProd_202111
tblProd_202112
tblProd_202201
```

I am thinking to schedule:

```
1 - update during the night to replicate/publish end of day data
2 - replicate tables in real-time to check the production status
```

Is it possible for the the real-time schedule to use the source table name as a variable?
Every day the data from the previous day to be deleted.
When a new month starts the source table to be automatically updated (a new table to be used as a source) and the old data to be removed. I updated the sp_addarticle below in order to describe better what I want to achieve.

Thank you in advance!

```
exec sp_addarticle
 @publication = N'VS_DWH_Test_pub', 
 @article = N'tblProd_yyyymm', 
 @source_owner = N'dbo', 
 @source_object = @tblProd_yyyymm, 
 @type = N'logbased', 
 @description = null, 
 @creation_script = null, 
 @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', 
 @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, 
 @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual', 
 @destination_table = N'tbl_Production_Today', 
 @destination_owner = N'dbo', 
 @vertical_partition = N'false', 
 @ins_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSins_dbo' + @tblProd_yyyymm,
 @del_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSdel_dbo' + @tblProd_yyyymm, 
 @upd_cmd = N'SCALL sp_MSupd_dbo' + @tblProd_yyyymm, 
 @filter_clause = N'[PRD_DATE] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)